# Deploy App to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have deployed my Node.js bot to heroku using the cli. WHen I try to open the app, it crashes with this error in log:

```
2018-02-20T12:34:24.132994+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! drvinebot@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2018-02-20T12:34:24.133186+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-02-20T12:34:24.133463+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2018-02-20T12:34:24.133682+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
drvinebot@1.0.0 start script.
2018-02-20T12:34:24.133887+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a 
problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-02-20T12:34:56.072459+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/" host=drvinebot.herokuapp.com 
request_id=8bf3595c-2ff8-4950-828c-0668e86e92bb fwd="106.203.157.18" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-20T12:34:57.812751+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=drvinebot.herokuapp.com 
request_id=f716154a-35e7-446d-b05d-bca3bc26c06c fwd="106.203.157.18" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-20T12:35:43.707329+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/" host=drvinebot.herokuapp.com 
request_id=b0b38a2c-8164-44ca-bdf7-1f426bb327b3 fwd="106.203.157.18" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-20T12:35:45.472294+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=drvinebot.herokuapp.com 
request_id=44814f37-d547-49c3-9cb4-d2454cedcb29 fwd="106.203.157.18" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-20T12:41:11.946966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/" host=drvinebot.herokuapp.com 
request_id=af3e6bff-32d0-4a7a-8a72-b847d8b5b642 fwd="106.203.191.138" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-20T12:41:13.583622+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=drvinebot.herokuapp.com 
request_id=63f94976-a986-48cb-81c3-a46706f782dc fwd="106.203.191.138" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here's my package.json file:

```
  "name": "drvinebot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "Joseph Joey",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
   "dependencies": {
     "express": "^4.16.2",
     "helmet": "^3.11.0",
     "twit": "^2.2.9"
      }
   }
```

Previously, I was using nodemon and app still crashed, so I changed my procfile to this:

```
web: npm start
```

to start the server using npm scripts. I don't seem to understand what's wrong here. Can someone help me out? 
Thanks.

Comment: Use process.env.PORT on server creation time.

Comment: I'm not using express, although it's added in pkg.json file. Where do I add that statement?

Comment: But in your package.json file you added dependency for express.

Comment: I have added the port and express. App doesn't crash when opened but says cannot get.. what does this mean pls?

Comment: Were you able to get your bot working successfully locally? If your bot is not a web app then you will need to set up your Procfile differently

Comment: No, it didn't work. Locally I don't see the kind of behavior I want but no errors too. Can you help?